# XAMPP: Apache and MySQL shutdown Unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, apache, web, xampp

I have been using XAMPP for long but it is not working now. I have tried some common solutions (like changing port..etc) but they are not working. If  you could help it would be a great help to me.

Error: Apache Unexpectedly Shutdown
Error: MySQL Unexpectedly Shutdown

```
Error Log Apache

[Fri Nov 14 00:55:34.619149 2014] [:error] [pid 1172:tid 1688] [client ::1:51627] script 'D:/xampp/htdocs/finals/index199.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/finals/index14.php
[Fri Nov 14 12:37:28.782388 2014] [cgi:error] [pid 1172:tid 1700] [client ::1:53466] script not found or unable to stat: D:/xampp/htdocs/finals/html_images.asp, referer: http://localhost/finals/index14.php
```

Comment: if any more details are required please comment

Comment: Please provide some error log in detail.

Answer (score -1):

This guide will help you to fix the issue.

http://www.fwait.com/fix-xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly/

Comment: while providing links to answer questions, it's better to write the actual steps that contain the answer as web content can change from time to time

Answer (score -1):

Open Xampp Start Apache and Mysql .

If it doesn't start open Netstat and check whether any ports using the Sql and Apache ports.

Now click on Config and Do as follows.

Change the ports from 80 and 443 to 8080 and 4433 respectively.

If the problem still persits. Uninstall Xampp and Reinstall it without reverting changes. It worked for me hope it works for u too